# Program is running in loop while reading input

Tags: c, input

I got a problem while reading my input. I am getting input with `fgetc(stdin)`. Before the equations I get number of equations. My code looks like this

```
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        do
        {               
           c=fgetc(stdin);

           if(c!='+' && c!='-' && c!='\n' && !isspace(c) && c!='=' && c!=EOF)
           {
               l++;
               equation[l]=c;
           }

           if(/* other conditions*/) eqToGauss(i,l,s,gaussMatrix,equation,sign);

        } while (c!= '\n');

    }
```

Problem is that, at the end of the penultimate lane(lane 8, after number 584), it gets '\n' and after that it won't stop the program but acts like it is running in loop. Xcode debug goes into assembler mode and the next character it reads since that moment is '\xff'. That algorithm works fine with short/ less equations.
This input is without empty lines after equations.

> > 299 x2 + 529 x3 + 194 x5 + 282 x3 + 364 x5 + 135 x4 + 388 x1 + 492 x2 + 236 x4 + 165 x2 +     557 x1 = 135 x3 + 26 x2 + 566
> >     482 x2 + 582 x5 = 530 x3 + 417 x1 + 424 x3 + 147 x5 + 81 x4 + 143 x3 + 195 x4 + 8 x2 + 479
> >     532 x5 + 61 x4 + 318 x4 + 288 x5 + 573 x5 + 162 x4 = 99 x4 + 44 x3 + 190 x1 + 60
> >     224 x1 + 145 x4 + 29 x4 + 1 x1 + 549 x5 + 186 x5 + 509 x4 + 178 x4 + 321 x1 + 320 x1 = 172 x4 + 537 x5 + 15
> >     398 x5 + 79 x5 + 357 x2 + 153 x5 + 37 x5 + 301 x1 + 174 x5 + 111 x2 = 170 x4 + 208 x1 + 368 x3 + 14 x4 + 100 x2 + 531 x2 + 578 x3 + 510 x4 + 583 x1 + 281
> >     301 x5 + 394 x5 + 272 x3 + 514 x5 = 412 x2 + 288 x4 + 182 x5 + 218 x1 + 210
> >     331 x5 + 333 x4 + 376 x2 + 490 x5 + 275 x5 + 105 x4 + 498 x2 + 152 x3 + 51 x2 = 328 x4 + 135 x5 + 452 x4 + 62 x5 + 533 x1 + 261 x3 + 527 x1 + 124 x5 + 295 x4 + 532 x2 + 4
> >     388 x2 + 415 x4 + 172 x4 + 403 x5 + 30 x1 = 511 x3 + 231 x5 + 104 x2 + 516 x2 + 380 x2 + 274 x5 + 522 x2 + 584
> >     554 x1 + 434 x4 + 288 x5 + 98 x2 + 85 x5 + 413 x2 + 40 x1 = 584 x3 + 113 x2 + 262 x5 + 348 x5 + 285 x5 + 328 x4 + 351 x4 + 77 x5 + 149 x5 + 170 x1 + 203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the EOF(end-of-file) character with fgetc and can't exit the loop as the exit statement
 is `c != '\n'`, but as long the EOF is in the stream the fgetc won't consume it and won't change variable `c`, thus causing infinite loop.

Comment: Yea but how can there be the EOF after penultimate equation?

Comment: @DávidKaya 0xFF is basically  EOF is `c` is char.

Comment: if I go with `while (c!= '\n' || c!= EOF);`, it still ends up in infinite loop.

Comment: What type is `c` in your case? Is it `char`?

Comment: Change it to `int`, and change your exit condition to `while (c!= '\n' && c!= EOF);`

Comment: Note that you are not testing for EOF until *AFTER* you can done your parsing. You need to test for it *BEFORE* you try to parse. Change you logic from a do-while to a while-do.

Comment: It will not parse equation with `\xff`, I got conditions there to not parse with useless chars. So it will end anyways. It's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for EOF on fgetc() -- the 0xFF implies end of file, but I don't see anything in your code fragment that stops reading input on EOF.

```
if( (c = fgetc(stdin)) == EOF )
{
    printf( "end of input\n" );
    exit( 0 );
}
```